# username to touch the right corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to make this text to touch the right side of the screen....
I gave margin but its not moving to the right side.....
wanted my user nmae to  be on the right extreme

http://jsfiddle.net/KthYy/embedded/result/

User info: test1@defie.co

```
<div class="companyLogo">
                <a class="brand" href="http://intra.defie.co/%3C?=%20HOME_URL%20;?%3E" style="">
                Company LOGO
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse"></div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>




            <div class="login-container">

                <span class="userInfo"><span class="mailId">User info: test1@defie.co</span><span><a href="http://intra.defie.co/Account/logout">[LOG OUT]</a></span></span>
                        </div>          <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bad English, unorganized HTML, no CSS, and there's one million way to solve your problem but we need to know how you are doing your layout, if its a table, if you are using floats..

Comment: @AliBassam i understand your frustration but the jsfiddle shows it all [ http://jsfiddle.net/KthYy/embedded/result/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set in your CSS rules right padding of 133 pixels for your userInfo SPAN:

```
padding-right: 133px;
```

That's preventing it from displaying right-most. Remove that declaration or set it to 0. You might also want to set text-align property to 'right' for your login-container:

```
.login-container {text-align:right;}
```

That's what you were thinking of?

Cheers!